# Not able to connect to Atlas Cluster because of SSL Certificate Expired

Tags: python, mongodb, ssl, pymongo, flask-mongoengine

I have an api using mongodb atlas as the database. It was working fine until one day it started throwing out this error:

`pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: cluster0-shard-00-00.gnqpe.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1129)`

Here's the code invoking the database:

```
DB_URI='mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@clusterdetails/databasename?retryWrites=true&w=majority'

from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine

db = MongoEngine()

def initialize_db(app):    
    db.init_app(app)
```

I have been trying to fix this but haven't been successfull. Also noticed that mongoDB compass also takes forever to connect to the atlas cluster.

I am using windows10.

Comment: I am also having these issues with a few programs that use urllib and websocket. Its weird because connecting to some sources through urllib or websockets work just fine but others get this certificate expired error. I think it may have something to do with the DST Root CA X3 certificate expiring today (9/30/2021). Have you found any solutions to this yet?

Comment: I don't think its a solution a such, but for now it what seems to work is setting 2 more arguments in the connection URI  as ```ssl=true&ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE```. I was able to make the connection, now but I am pretty sure this ain't the right method.

Comment: Do you have an option to select a different root CA in the Atlas configuration?

Comment: No there isn't any option as such on Atlas